# Flip a 3D card with CSS

Tags: css, 3d, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm trying to make a **3D card flipping effect with *CSS*** like this.

[image: 3D flipping card with CSS]

The difference is that I want to use only *CSS* to implement it.

Here is the code I tried:

```css
/*** LESS: ***/

    .card-container {
        position: relative;
        height: 12rem;
        width: 9rem;
        perspective: 30rem;
        .card {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;            
            div {
                position: absolute;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }
            .front {
                background-color: #66ccff;
            }
            .back {
                background-color: #dd8800;
                backface-visibility: hidden;
                transition: transform 1s;
                &:hover {
                    transform: rotateY(180deg);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
HTML:
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front"><span>Front</span></div>
    <div class="back"><span>Back</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue is that the card doesn't flip, it snaps from back to front like this:

[image: Flipping card effect not working]

Is it possible to implement this **3d card flip on hover** effect using only *CSS*?

Comment: The "front" does not get animated. Set its rotation to 180, 360 when you hover over it similar to the back. 360 degrees is similar to 0, but should maintain the same spinning direction.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I simplified the code to make it shorter and make the **3d card flip on hover**. The card flips on the Y axis from the front face to the back face this is what it looks like:

[image: CSS 3D flipping card on hover]

Here is an example of a simple **CSS only flipping card** the flip animation is launched on hover :

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 50vh;
  height: 80vh;
  perspective: 500px;
  margin: 10vh auto 50vh;
}

.front,
.back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 1s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.front {
  background-color: #66ccff;
}

.back {
  background-color: #dd8800;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card:hover .front {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card:hover .back {
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="front"><span>Front</span></div>
  <div class="back"><span>Back</span></div>
</div>
```

This is what I changed in your code for the flip effect:

- the front face wasn't rotated on th Y axis on hover
- the hover effect was launched when the `.back` div was hovered. This can create flickering as that div is rotating and "disapears" at mid rotation. It's better to launch the animation when the static parent is hovered.
- the first parent isn't really usefull so I removed it

Comment: Wow, that's wonderful~ I was trying to hover on the parent but i missed `transform: rotateY(360deg);` which led to a complete blank when hovering. The front and back just flipped and hided together... Thank you for you detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

yes it can be done using CSS only and you can do by using CSS3 animation property. Here is example of flipping card animation.

```
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">
      <span class="fa fa-user"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="back">User</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
.card-container {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 12px;
    perspective: 900px;
    text-align: center;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.front, .back {
  position: absolute;
  background: #FEC606;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 27px 55px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 17px 17px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.front {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.back {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.card-container:hover .card {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

You can also read this article about [CSS Flip Animation on Hover](http://codeconvey.com/css-flip-animation-on-hover-flipping-card/)

You can also find demo and download source from the article.