# Understanding CSS rotate3d axis of rotation

Tags: html, css, animation, 3d, rotation

I am having trouble understanding css rotate3d method. Could someone please explain how the axis of rotation is obtained from the x, y, and z values since they are not given in degrees?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate3d + some math .. and there is an angle at the end, the x,y,z define only the axis `The amount of rotation created by rotate3d() is specified by three <number>s and one <angle>. The <number>s represent the x-, y-, and z-coordinates of the vector denoting the axis of rotation.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flip a 3D card with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41461101/flip-a-3d-card-with-css)

Answer (score -4):

3D rotate mean in 3 direction.
First, you must be understand Rotate.

```
#myDiv {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(150deg); /* Safari */
    transform: rotateX(150deg);
}
```

rotateY()

```
#myDiv {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(130deg); /* Safari */
    transform: rotateY(130deg);
}
```

rotateZ()

```
#myDiv {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(90deg); /* Safari */
    transform: rotateZ(90deg);
}
```

It is just an example, you use these three properties to make 3D rotate.

Comment: This doesn't explain anything.